# Convert array (or vector) of u16 (or u32, u64) to array of u8

Tags: rust

I have no problem to do it for [u16 to u8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53314005/how-can-i-convert-the-lower-upper-8-bits-of-a-u16-to-a-u8-in-rust) using bit shifts and cast but how could I do it with an array of u16? Even ideally I would prefer to convert directly from vec to [u8]. What would be the most elegant way to do it?

```rs
&my_vector[..] // my vector converted to [u16] but I need [u8]
```

Comment: Use [`slice::align_to`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.align_to)

Answer (score 4):

Was able to make it work thanks to @Aplet123 insight:

#### From Vector to bytes array

From Vec to [u8]

```rs
let mut my_u16_vec : Vec<u16> = Vec::new();
let my_u8_array = my_u16_vec.align_to::<u8>().1;
```

---

#### From bytes array back to Vector

From [u8] to Vec

```rs
let n = my_u16_vec.len() * 2;
let my_u16_vec_bis:Vec<u16> = (my_u8_array[..n].align_to::<u16>().1).to_vec();
```

---

#### Getting the bytes right

And then reverse bytes as values are written reversely in memory due to endianness:

```
for e in my_u16_vec_bis:Vec.iter() {
    let value = e >> 8 | (e & 0xff) << 8;
}
```

Comment: Note that your "bytes array to Vector" code only works if the byte array is properly aligned, which it may not be if it has been sent through a network socket or a file.

Comment: Good point, thank you @Jmb. I check for the alignment before.